# Prism環境でMahApps.Metroを参照したWPFアプリケーションのDLLをマージできない

Tags: c#, wpf

Prism環境下で，MahApps.Metroを参照したWPFアプリケーションについて，この[サイト](https://qiita.com/VBmouiya/items/d388d49328cb0298eb96)の方法でDLLとアプリケーションを一つにまとめようとしたところ，下記のエラーが出てビルドに失敗します。

- エラーコード   CS1508
- 説明　リソース識別子 'System.Windows.Interactivity.dll'は既にこのアセンブリで使用されています。
- ファイル　CSC

回避策はないものでしょうか？

ソースコード
https://github.com/dicehira/sandbox

Answer (score 1):

自己解決の報告
プロジェクトファイルに追記するコードを下記に修正

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)" Condition="'%(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.Extension)' == '.dll'">
```

↓

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)" Condition="('%(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.Extension)' == '.dll') AND ('%(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.Filename)' != 'System.Windows.Interactivity')">
```

内容（予想）：重複したSystem.Windows.Interactivity.dllのみリソースに含めない。
おそらくMahApps.Metro内のSystem.Windows.Interactivity.dllが補完しているため
動作する。